# order of parameters of function call of python

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

Suppose I have a `function` with `10 args`:

```
def foo(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4.....):
```

Sometimes, I need to call it with only `arg1` and another time `arg1, arg4`, or `arg4 , arg7`.

My program doesn't specify the type of the function call. Does python have a way to help me?

Comment: Use default argument parameters

Comment: `def foo(arg1 = val, arg2 = val2, arg3 = val3,...):`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way to do it is to make the parameters optional:

```
def foo(arg1=None,arg2=None,arg3=None...)
```

which can be called like this:

```
foo(arg1=1,arg3=2)
```

or like this:

```
a = {'arg1':1, 'arg3':2}
foo(**a)
```

If this list of parameters is spinning out of control you could simply use [`**kwargs`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) to let your function take an optional number of (named) keyword arguments:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    print kwargs

params = {'arg1':1, 'arg2':2}

foo(**params)         # Version 1
foo(arg1=3,arg2=4)    # Version 2
```

Output:

```
{'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 2}
{'arg1': 3, 'arg2': 4}
```

> **Note:** You can use one asterisk (`*`) for an arbitrary number of arguments that will be [wrapped up in a tuple](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).

Comment: What if there is a variable named "arg1", identically named as the optional parameter in foo(), outside of foo()? Will it cause conflict?

Comment: no, it won't cause conflict Sean. I think you're describing foo(arg1=arg1). Python interpreters know the token to the left of '=' refers to the name of the param.

Answer (score 5):

Give your args a default value like `None`:

```
def foo(arg1=None, arg2=None, ..., arg10=None):
```

Now, when calling the function pass a dictionary of keyword arguments:

```
kwargs = {
    'arg1': 'test',
    'arg7': 'test2',
}

foo(**kwargs)
```

It's equivalent to:

```
foo('test', None, None, None, ..., 'test2', None, None, None)
```

Or, to be more specific:

```
foo(arg1='test', arg7='test2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [keyword arguments](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments)